# Search API View, search relation fields

Tags: entities, search, views

I am creating a search api view based on [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) (with Database backend for now (will change to solr later)).

I have 2 entities that are being indexed i.e. **project** and **client**.

A **project** contains a *projectnumber* and an entity reference to a client. The **client** contains a *firstname* and *lastname*.

I have added a view that shows the *projectnumbers* and (via relation to client entity) the *first* and *lastname*.

I want my exposed fulltext search to search these 3 fields (*projectnumber*, *firstname* and *lastname*).

The weird thing is that he only seems to search on **projectnumber** and not the *first* and *lastname*.

Does anybody have a workaround/solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 areas you need to check this is included.  It's common to have applied to the search and not realise it needs to applied in views also.

I take it so far you have made the fields in

configuration > search api > Operations 'EDIT'

"Fields" tab > 'Add Related Fields ' at the bottom.

Now you also need to add the Fields in

structure > views > your view

Filter Criteria >

On the right hand side look for 'Searched Fields'  - make sure all the fields your searching are in here.

I hope that solves it for you .